# Can built-in functions deal with stochastic delay differential equations (SDDE)?

Tags: differential-equations, stochastic-calculus

I know that functions like `NDSolve` can deal with delay differential equations and in the meanwhile, functions like `ItoProcess` and `RandomFunction` handle stochastic differential equations. So I wonder whether any built-in functions can handle it when the above two cases are combined together. For example, I naively tried the below codes by just slightly modifying the first example of `ItoProcess` (`x[t] -> x[t - 1]` in the square root)

```
proc = ItoProcess[\[DifferentialD]x[t] == -x[t] \[DifferentialD]t + Sqrt[1 + x[t - 1]^2] 
       \[DifferentialD]w[t], x[t], {x, 1}, t, w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]]
RandomFunction[proc, {0., 5., 0.01}]
```

The first row of codes runs seemly well, but the second one just returns a `RandomFunction::unsproc` error, specifically `` RandomFunction::unsproc: The specification `<Ito process>` is not a random process recognized by the system. ``.

Or do I have to implement a version myself with Euler method alike?

---

**Update**

(According to @AlexTrounev 's answer)

Conclusion: The answer is yes.

The basic idea is to feed a random function $ w'(t) $ to `NDSolve`.

Comment: The first line also not working well since it returns undefined function `ItoProcess[{{-x[t]}, {{Sqrt[1 + x[t][-1 + t]^2]}}, 
  x[t]}, {{x}, {1}}, {t, 0}]`, where ` x[t][-1 + t]` is not defined.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thx for the observation that I did not notice before.

Comment: ItoProcess requires a simultaneous differential equations. simflr might by simulation flailour. This is defintion step and simulation step. Simulation fails complete because the definition is erroneous. LIke the de the process is simultaneous only. [Stochastic differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_differential_equation). It works long if negative times are avoided, but with messages. Look at [how_to_solve_stochastic_delay_differential_equations](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_solve_stochastic_delay_differential_equations)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For numerical model we can define `RandomFunction[]` with `WienerProcess[]` outside of `NDSolve` and then solve stochastic delay equation using standard algorithm

```
SeedRandom[1234];
pWe = RandomFunction[WienerProcess[.3, .5], {0., 5., 0.01}][[2, 1, 
  1]]; pp = 
 Interpolation[
  Table[{5 (i - 1)/(Length[pWe] - 1), pWe[[i]]}, {i, Length[pWe]}], 
  InterpolationOrder -> 3];


sde = {x'[t] + x[t] - Sqrt[1 + x[t - 1]^2] pp'[t] == 0, 
   x[t /; t <= 0] == 0};
sol = NDSolve[sde, x, {t, 0, 5}]
```

Visualisation

```
Plot[{pp[t], x[t] /. sol}, {t, 0, 5}, FrameLabel -> {"t", ""}, 
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False, PlotLegends -> {"pp", "x"}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Nice answer! Thx!

Comment: BTW, the result of `RandomFunction` has a property `"PathFunction"`, which can be used to extract the interpolation function.

Comment: Yes, we can also use  `"PathFunction"` but it is not the same as  `pp`.

Comment: This experiments with Wiener instead of Ito with noise from a Wiener stochastic process. This solve a delayed differential equation not a differential equation with Ito stochastic methodologies. This chops off short term biases and does not really solve the question.

Comment: @SteffenJaeschke Why not just to post your answer?

Comment: How do I solve Milstein approximations in mathematica?

Comment: @areebaBajwa Do you mean option `Method->"Milstein"` for `RandomFunction` in a case of `ItoProcess`?

Comment: @Alex Trounev how do i solve system of equations solve by Method->"Milstein" approximation...kindly help me...

Comment: @areebaBajwa What kind of system do you try to solve?

Comment: @Alex Trounev this is a system. I don't have any idea about Milstein and Euler-Maruyama method in Mathematica coding … I am a new on Mathematica. This is the application of stochastic differential equation...if you have any example about Euler and Milstein approximation...kindly upload it. I am very thankful to you..